# Is the call stack and execution context used when calling functions using the return value of other functions as arguments?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I learnt about how call stacks and execution contexts are used in recursive functions. Just curious if the same method is used when we call functions using the return value of other functions as arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would not be the same. Where with recursive calls a function context remains on the stack while the recursive call is made, this is not the case when you make function calls of which the return arguments are used in a *subsequent* call.

So for instance, if we have three functions `f`, `g` and `h`, and this code:

```
result = f(g(1), h(2))
```

...then there is not much difference (with respect to the call stack) with this code:

```
result1 = g(1)
result2 = h(2)
result = f(result1, result2)
```

The only difference is that the function results are *also* stored in variables `result1` and `result2`. But the main point here is that the call to `h` is not made before the call of `g` has returned, and the call to `f` is not made before `h` has returned: there is no situation where one of these function execution contexts is on the stack while a deeper call is made.